# How to get value from one textbox and assign to next coming textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the textbox value and trying to assign  next coming text field.[image]

Just like in image ,when i try to add some value to my second textfield (like 260 ) it will fill the next (kashif first textfield in example) field  with the previous field value.This will work after the  second field entry and so one.Nothing for the first.
Name and id are dynamically generated like for the first it will be size_min[1_1_0]( for 240) and size_max[1_1_0] (for 260).I am confuse due to dynamic ids of the field.
This is my html code :

```
    <div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">

    <h4 class="icon-head"><?php echo Mage::helper('mymodule')->__($value['label']." (".$std['name'].")") ?></h4>

    </div>
    <div>

    <div id="addanswer_form" class="fieldset">
            <?php  

  $results = $read->fetchAll("select * from  mytable where standards_id =".$std['standards_id']);
  foreach($results as $mykey=>$myvar)
  {
?>
    <div class="hor-scroll" style=" margin-bottom: 2px; ">
    <div style=" width:70px; float:left;">
        <label for="name" ><?php echo ucwords($myvar['value']);?> </label>
        </div>
        <div style=" float:left;">
<input type="text" class="required-entry input-text required-entry" style=" float:left; width:60px;"  value="" name="size_min[<?php echo $value['dimension_id']."_".$std['standards_id']."_".$myvar['value_id']?>]" id="size_min[<?php echo $value['dimension_id']."_".$std['standards_id']."_".$myvar['value_id']?>]">
 </div> <span style="float:left;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
 <div style=" float:left;">
<input type="text" class="required-entry input-text required-entry" style=" float:left; width:60px;"  value="" name="size_max[<?php echo $value['dimension_id']."_".$std['standards_id']."_".$myvar['value_id']?>]" id="size_max[<?php echo $value['dimension_id']."_".$std['standards_id']."_".$myvar['value_id']?>]" >
 </div>
 </div>
<?php   } // end of foreach loop for standard values  
        ?>
</div>
```

**This is output in html formate:**

```
<div class="fieldset" id="addanswer_form">
    <div style=" margin-bottom: 2px; " class="hor-scroll">
        <div style=" width:70px; float:left;">
            <label for="name">Neemh</label>
        </div>
        <div style=" float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="size_min[1_1_7]" name="size_min[1_1_7]" value="" style=" float:left; width:60px;" class="required-entry input-text required-entry">
        </div> <span style="float:left;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
        <div style=" float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="size_max[1_1_7]" name="size_max[1_1_7]" value="" style=" float:left; width:60px;" class="required-entry input-text required-entry">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=" margin-bottom: 2px; " class="hor-scroll">
        <div style=" width:70px; float:left;">
            <label for="name">Kashif</label>
        </div>
        <div style=" float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="size_min[1_1_8]" name="size_min[1_1_8]" value="" style=" float:left; width:60px;" class="required-entry input-text required-entry">
        </div> <span style="float:left;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
        <div style=" float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="size_max[1_1_8]" name="size_max[1_1_8]" value="" style=" float:left; width:60px;" class="required-entry input-text required-entry">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=" margin-bottom: 2px; " class="hor-scroll">
        <div style=" width:70px; float:left;">
            <label for="name">Shamma</label>
        </div>
        <div style=" float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="size_min[1_1_10]" name="size_min[1_1_10]" value="" style=" float:left; width:60px;" class="required-entry input-text required-entry">
        </div> <span style="float:left;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
        <div style=" float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="size_max[1_1_10]" name="size_max[1_1_10]" value="" style=" float:left; width:60px;" class="required-entry input-text required-entry">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Showing some HTML would be useful. Do the textboxes have any class attributes? Are there always two in a row?

Comment: You could target by index.

Comment: @Blade0rz I updated my question with html code .

Comment: Don't ever use two elements with the same id.

Comment: Your HTML has a `</div>` tag that doesn't match an opening `<div>` tag; can you post a bit more of the HTML, perhaps the HTML for the  entire "Chest" section?

Comment: @KamilT Sorry i put the old code for Id.I change it now.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman How about my previous comment? I'm currently interested in answering this question (that won't last that much longer), but need you to show the entire HTML for that section in order for me to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I updated my question again and put all my html code with php.You can check it now.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman PHP isn't useful, because that's not what the jQuery executes against (I'm also not a PHP programmer, though I've seen enough of it now that I can figure it out). Show the generated HTML, not the server-side code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Check now question with output in html formate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following DOM traversal code:

```
$('.hor-scroll div:nth-of-type(3) input:text').on('input', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.hor-scroll').next().find('input:text:eq(0)').val(this.value);
});
```

That selects the `<input type="text"/>` element from the third `<div>` element for each of the `<div class="hor-scroll">` elements, which is the second textbox in each row. Then, relative to that textbox, it finds the first textbox of the next row, and sets its value.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPpZe/)

Comment: .I try your code and it gives me TypeError: $(...).on is not a function.$('.hor-scroll div:nth-of-type(3) input:text').on('input', function(e) {}.do you have any idea why this error comes to me.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Sounds like you're using an older version of jQuery that doesn't include `.on()`. Try switching that to `bind` instead.

Comment: Thanks yes the error was due to old js.I update it to 1.9 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

add class "second" to second text

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.second').blur(function(){

              $(this).next().val($this.val());

      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: That would only work if the very next element in the DOM was the next textbox, but that's not the case; there are other elements wrapping them.

Comment: $(this).next().is('input:text').val($this.val());

Comment: That still doesn't work because it's not consistent with the HTML. You *can't use `.next()`*.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend creating an ID for each of the textboxes and then creating the code onkeyup to update the next field.

I assume myvar is part of a while loop. I would create an int that goes up for each cycle through the loop and then create an ID based on that number.

Example:

```
<div class="entry-edit">
<div class="entry-edit-head">

<h4 class="icon-head"><?php echo Mage::helper('mymodule')->__($value['label']." (".$std['name'].")") ?></h4>

</div>
<div>

<div id="addanswer_form" class="fieldset">
<?php  

$results = $read->fetchAll("select * from  mytable where standards_id =".$std['standards_id']);
$looped = 0;
foreach($results as $mykey=>$myvar)
{
    ?>
    <div class="hor-scroll" style=" margin-bottom: 2px; ">
    <div style=" width:70px; float:left;">
    <label for="name" ><?php echo ucwords($myvar['value']);?> </label>
    </div>
    <div style=" float:left;">
    <input type="text" class="required-entry input-text required-entry" style=" float:left; width:60px;" onkeyup="update_id(<? echo $looped; ?>);" value="" name="size_min[<?php echo $value['dimension_id']."_".$std['standards_id']."_".$myvar['value_id']?>]" id="first_<? echo $looped; ?>">
    </div> <span style="float:left;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;- &nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
    <div style=" float:left;">
    <input type="text" class="required-entry input-text required-entry" style=" float:left; width:60px;"  value="" name="size_max[<?php echo $value['dimension_id']."_".$std['standards_id']."_".$myvar['value_id']?>]" id="second_<? echo $looped; ?>" >
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php   
    $looped++;
     } // end of foreach loop for standard values  
     ?>
     </div>
```

Then create this javascript function:

```
<script>
function update_id(id){
            next = id+1;
            if($("#first_"+next).length){ //if the next first checkbox exists, set the value from the previous second checkbox.

                $("#first_"+next).val($("#second_"+id).val());
            }
        }
</script>
```

Notice the onkeyup method and the updated id's along with the `$looped` variable.

Comment: I am using three variables for id and name if you see my html ouput you will get it.You code seem to work for one variable .

Comment: Whenever you type into the second textbox of each row it should auto fill in the next coming rows first textbox. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @ethree It received a downvote (from me) when you were first suggesting using `.after()`, which was totally irrelevant. Now, though, it's because you're using inline event handlers and some other bad practices, and making the whole thing considerably more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @ethree i tried your code and it show SyntaxError: missing ; before statement   int next = id+1;

Answer (score -1):

You might do something like this:

```
$('#text_of_260').on('keyup',function(e){

  // get the new value from the event 
  console.log('e',e); 
  // to get the value you might use : e.srcElement.value or e.srcElement.innerText //
  var new_value = e.value();  

  // get the second text box

  $('#text_show_get_value').val(new_value);

});
```

Answer (score -2):

This might help

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var value;
         var j;
     var count = $(".required-entry").length;
     $(".required-entry").blur(function(){
       for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
          value =  $('.size_max[1_1_'+i).val();
             j= i+1;
           $('.size_min[1_1_'+j).val(value);
         }

      });


 });
```

Comment: I mention in my question that the ids are dynamic and in your code you are only changing last value (j).In my question all the values 1 and _1 and _0 are dynamic.